# Rails seems unable to find some gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, gemfile

Yesterday, everything worked fine. You can see my previous Gemfile [here](https://gist.github.com/4168344).

Then, I added some groups like you can see [here](https://gist.github.com/4168353).

Since then, I got this message:

```
Exiting
/Users/adrien/code/adserver/backoffice/config/initializers/airbrake.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Airbrake (NameError)
```

[[AirbrakeFullStackTrace](https://gist.github.com/4168359)]

As I couldn't figure out why I met this behavior and I was stuck, I tried to require `airbrake` in the corresponding `initializer`. I relaunched the server and I got the message:

```
Exiting
/Users/adrien/code/adserver/backoffice/config/initializers/devise.rb:4:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Devise (NameError)
```

[[DeviseFullStackTrace](https://gist.github.com/4168369)]

Like the error with Airbrake, I required `devise` in the initializer file and relaunched the server. I got this:

```
Exiting
/Users/adrien/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:50:in `method_missing': undefined local variable or method `acts_as_sane_tree' for #<Class:0x007fd3363593f8> (NameError)
```

[[ActsAsSaneTreeFullStackTrace](https://gist.github.com/4168391)]

I required `acs_as_sane_tree` in my model file, relaunched the server and **now**, it works.

Does anybody can tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for having bored people. I just got it. For those who play with groups in Gemfile, here is the thing to know and remember.

In `config/application.rb`, you can find the following instruction:

```
Bundler.require *Rails.groups(:assets) if defined?(Bundler)
```

You have to tell Bundler to include any exotic group you added in your Gemfile. So, in my case, that gave us:

```
Bundler.require *Rails.groups(:assets, :rails, :frontoffice) if defined?(Bundler)
```

Some help found on the Bundler site, [Using Groups](http://gembundler.com/groups.html).